# Как передать масcив строк в WCF REST

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, httpwebrequest

Как передать массив строк в WCF REST, через DELETE запрос?

Контракт

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE")]
void DeleteFiles(string[] filesPath);
```

Вызов

```
public void DeleteFiles(string[] filesPath)
{
   var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8733/FileServer/DeleteFiles");
   request.Method = HttpMethod.Delete.Method;

   var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

   var sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
   foreach (var filePath in filesPath)
       sw.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filePath));

   request.GetResponse();
}
```

Метод `DeleteFiles(string[] filesPath)` вызывается, но переменная `filesPath = null`.

Для службы использую `webHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

Cервер ожидает увидеть параметры в параметрах запроса, а не в теле. Delete -- это не put/post. Однако с передачей массива в параметре не все так просто. Как правильно сделать вызов, можно почитать [на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/354823/1985167).

Comment: Да я видел этот пост спасибо, но мне не хотелось бы вносить столько изменений из-за одного метода. Думаю может массив строк передавать через POST запрос в виде Stream, а на стороне сервере распарсить принятый Stream в массив строк.

Comment: @Мурад можно и так. Не забудьте только сменить веб-метод.